# Ruby on rails objects associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two objects - User and Reviews. One User can write many reviews, but one review can be written by one user. Every user has a picture. I have:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

Why can't I do the following?

```
review.user.picture
```

Comment: Most likely because your review does not belong to any user.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your question. You do not state any problem (with an error message, or an unexpected behavior). You simply ask if you can do something. So my answer is a question: Why haven't you tried by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You have to establish `has_one`/`belongs_to` associations on `user`/`picture` models and of course to have appropriate database migrations (foreign key user_id on picture table and foreign key user_id on review table).

Models look like:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_one :picture
end

class Picture
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To try it, first create data in rails console:

```
user = User.create
review = Review.create user: user
picture = Picture.create user: user
```

Now you can find user picture if you have only reference to review object. Exit console and run again and type:

```
review = Review.last
review.user.picture
```

It returns picture object.

More info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you provided, I'm assuming you still need to set up a foreign key in the database. The database migration for the the reviews table should look similar to this:

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :reviews do |t|
   t.integer :user_id
   t.timestamps
  end
   add_index :reviews, :user_id
  end
end
```

Then you would be able to add a related `user_id` to a new review object. For instance, in rails console:

```
Review.new(user_id: 1)
```

Assuming that you defined `picture` as a column in your User table, you should be able to run `review.user.picture` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Method**

The bottom line is your `picture` method will not be present in your `user` model

You can either use an `instance method` to create some functionality in your `User` model, use an [`ActiveRecord Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), or use something like `Paperclip` to provide an appended object on your `user` object

---

**Association**

You'll need to create the correct association for your `review` & `picture` objects -

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reviews
   has_one  :picture
end

#app/models/picture.rb
Class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@review = Review.find params[:id]
@picture = @review.user.picture
```

A bonus tip for this is if you wanted to ensure compatibility with the [law of dementer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), you could use the [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method in your `user` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   delegate :attribute, to: :picture, prefix: true
end
```

This will allow you to call the likes of:

```
@review.user.picture_name
```

---

**Paperclip**

If you're using a picture model to store images, you *may* wish to use the likes of [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to give you the ability to use the functionality of images in your `Picture` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    delegate :url, to: :picture
end

#app/models/picture.rb
Class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :picture
end
```

---

These will all help you. Using this answer with `Иван Бишевац`'s will help you profusely :)